# Pygame : Getting rid of strange gradient effect on displayed image

Tags: python, image, graphics, pygame

Hello fellow programmers,

I wrote a little python program which is use to launch random games on a retrograming distribution, and I use pygame to display the image of the game before launching it

I use a background and my issue is that the background image is clean but when displaying it and the cover of the game over it, it appears with a strange ugly gradient effect as you can see there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaFV4.jpg

It appears mostly in the corner and the cover itself is entirely unaffected.

Here is my pygame code displaying both images :

```
    log('showPic %s' %file)
    # INITS
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    backgroundPicture = pygame.image.load(backgroundFile)
    picture = pygame.image.load(file)
    # # CREATE FULLSCREEN DISPLAY. X = 1920- Y = 1080
    fullscreen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080), FULLSCREEN)
    fullscreen.blit(backgroundPicture, (0,0))
    # # PASTE PICTURE ON FULLSCREEN
    x = (1920 - picture.get_width()) /2
    y = (1080 - picture.get_height()) /2
    fullscreen.blit(picture, (x,y))
    # # SHOW FULLSCREEN 
    pygame.display.flip()
    # # WAIT 5 SECONDS (need import time)
    time.sleep(5)
    # # EXIT PYGAME (Not needed but recommanded)
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.quit()
```

`backgroundPicture` is the background image and `picture` is the cover of the game, I combined the too like it appears in second capture.

So mainly I don't know much at all about display, images, graphical libraries and all that.
I think that this might be related to transparency or alpha layer or compression format of the image but I have no knowledge at all about that either.
The code is launched on a raspberry pi with a linux distribution, don't know much more about it.

Also strangely, one of my users said the strange gradient effect seems to disappear after ten or so launches of the script, but I couldn't reproduce that.

So what am I missing to get rid of that ugly effect ?

Here is the background image here if its characteristic might be related to the problem : 
[image: background.png]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Try calling `convert()` on both surfaces after loading: `backgroundPicture = pygame.image.load(backgroundFile).convert()` and `picture = pygame.image.load(file).convert()`

Comment: Hello sloth I've tried it as I did see this in another question, but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The effect you are seeing is called *"banding"*, see [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding). It is caused by not having enough bit-depth to represent fine gradations of colour and is most noticeable in large, untextured areas.

There are not many things you can do about it. Your options are basically:

- to go to a 16-bit setup instead of 8-bit, if **pygame** can do that, or
- add a small amount of random noise, or dithering to break it up.

Comment: Hello, thank you  for your explanation.  Just one question : "to go to a 16-bit setup instead of 8-bit, if pygame can do that" how can I do that ?    Also according to this [link](https://elinux.org/RPiconfig) it seems the default for the Raspberry Pi framebuffer is already 16bit.    Is there anything I can do on the image side ?   Another funnny thing is in Gimp the histogram for the image says there are only 256 colors (maybe for each R G B though) ? so far less than 16bits ?

Comment: I can't get the PNG file from `zippyfile` in order to look at it because it gives me a JPEG. Can you add the images into your question directly please - you should have a few more points now...

Comment: Added image in post, Mark